# site messes up in small screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a site with bootstrap and although most of it is responsive, there are a few elements that mess up a bit when the screen size is reduced.
Could you tell me how to correct this?

Here's what the element looks like in big screen.
[image]

And here's how it looks like on the small screen
[image]

Is there a way so the element maintains the same position even in small screens??
Any other ideas I should make it look on the small screen??

Here's the codepen link - [codepen link](http://codepen.io/silentarrowz/pen/BLNYQW)

```
   .container{
    text-align: center;
    width:80%;

}

.first{
    background:rgb(0,30,58);
    color:white;

}
.span1,.span2{
    font-size:36px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.span1{
color:rgb(72,174,137);
}

[type="text"]{
    border-radius:25px;
    padding-left:5px;
}

[type="submit"]{
    color:white;
    background-color: rgb(72,174,137);
    border-radius:25px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:-25px;
}
.use{
    max-height:85%;
    margin:0 auto;

}
.usediv{
    border:3px solid rgb(72,174,137);

    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    max-height:220px;
}
.usediv p{

    margin-top:10px;
}
.usediv img{
  position:relative;
  top:-25px;
}

.box{
 border:3px solid rgb(72,174,137);
 width:55%;
 margin:0 auto;
 max-height:210px;
}
/*
.box .img-responsive{
    margin-top:-20px;
}
*/
.para{
    text-align: left;
    margin-right:0;
    padding-right:0;
    padding-top:15px;
}
.para strong{
    font-weight:900;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.second{
    margin-bottom:30px;
    border:1px solid green;
    width:10%;
}
.threebox{
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-left:70px;


}
.col-md-4{
    height:40%;
}
.col-md-4 > p{
    background-color:white;
    border:2px solid white;
    border-top-color:green;
    width:200px;
    height:160px;
    box-shadow:10px 10px 15px;

}
.positions{
    margin-top:60px;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:-50px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.positions > h1{
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:bold;


}

.spanf{
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.features{
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom:40px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:rgb(242,243,245);

    height:1840px;
    z-index:1;
    padding-top:120px;

    border:2px solid red;
}


.features .row{

    width:65%;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:40px;

    padding-top:30px;
    padding-left:20px;
}



.features button{
    border-radius:20px;
}


.features img{
    /*width:98%;
    height:98%;*/

}
/*
.features .row .col-lg-6{

    padding-right:15px;
    padding-left: 2px;
}*/



/*
.img2{
  position:relative;
  left: 12px;
top: -12px;
box-shadow: -2px 2px 9px;

}
.img3{
    position:relative;
    top:-12px;
    left:-12px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 9px;
}

*/

.imgleft, .imgright{
    border:2px solid rgb(72,174,137);
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.imgleft img{
    position:relative;
    top:-15px;
    left:15px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 9px;
}

.imgright img{
    position:relative;
    top:-15px;
    left:-15px;
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 9px;
}

.textleft p{
    text-align:left;
}
.textright p{
    text-align: right;
}





.pillars{
    border:2px solid rgb(72,174,137);
    background-color: rgb(72,174,137);
    height:350px;
    margin-top:0;
}
```

Please advise what changes I should make to fix this thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have two solutions at the moment for you:

1) to remove `max-height` from `.usediv`.
**Affect:** divs going to be "longer".
[Check the output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBye3.png)

2) to add `overflow:auto;` to `.usediv`.
**Affect:** the div will still have it's max height and scroll on the right side will appear for users, BUT the image will be messed up little bit as it won't be *outside* the div as now.
[Check the output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkvNQ.png)

---

OR you can create a special css using **media queries** of bootstrap:
`@media(max-width:480px){}`
`@media(min-width:800px){}`

Of course you can use any width you need and you can create more than 1 in your css. And so your main style won't be messed up, and for smaller space you can choose other way to display content whether to use overflow or to increase height of div.

Comment: ok, so you mean this can be done with media queries only. right??

Comment: No, not only.
Basically you have 2 views: on large screen (which you like and is okay) and small screen (on which most of the style breaks).
So the easiest and the fastest solution is just to create styles for problematic parts using media queries.
For example you have that enoying div, what you do - is leaving as it is, but for screens that are smaller than screen size on the point when everything breaks down - make another style.
For checking the screen size: on web page make right click on mouse and choose "Inspect". You will see width and height on the top right side of the window.

Comment: Ah! thanks.
so the easiest and fastest solution is to create styles for problematic parts using media queries. I like that.
But I'd also like to know the proper way to do things.
I am learning this right now and would appreciate it if you could also tell me what is the proper way to do this i.e. how would a professional web developer do it??

Comment: @faraz write on my mail - ellenagolubeva@gmail.com and I could write you an organized mail to describe how to do it easily to avoid crushes if it's okay for you. Also I could share my personal experience in working with bootstrap

Comment: Thanks. Just sent you an email.

Answer (score 0):

You've specified the dimensions in pixels. Try to denote them using % where ever possible.
You could use auto for the green box's height. The green box will adjust it's height depending on the length of your text.